# Downgrade Galaxy Ace to stock rom without Odin

Tags: rom, samsung-galaxy-ace

I' install the CM7.2 on it using the CWM v5.0.2.6 Well now I'd like to retun to stock rom I found that I cannot connect my phone to the computer(I have a damaged micro usb on the phone) to use Odin Well is there any way to return to stock rom without odin, by using the SD card? Thank's

Comment: Did you make nandroid backup of stock ROM after installing CWM? Or do you have recovery flashable stock ROM zip?

Comment: I downloded the original firmware for my ace; but I dont have any backups